# How to revert a dynamic property of an object with QDataWidgetMapper?

Tags: qt

I have a form dialog QDialog for updating data of a QTableView row using QDataWidgetMapper. The item contains QString data, but I only want to show a QCheckBox and set the value in background on state change using a dynamic property on QCheckbox.

Everything (toFirst, toLast, toNext, toPrevious, submit) works as expected, **but revert does not undo** the shown state.

Is there a signal I can use? Or should I try to override the revert slot? Any suggestion?

(Code of other widgets removed to keep it simple)

```
EditDialog::EditDialog(QStandardItemModel &model, QModelIndex &current, QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    cbHomeCLI = new QCheckBox();
    // other widgets ......

    dataMapper->setModel(&model);
    dataMapper->setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper::ManualSubmit);
    dataMapper->addMapping(cbHomeCLI,3,"useCLI");

    // button connects for toFirst, toXXXX, ..., here ....        
    connect(bttnDiscard,&QPushButton::clicked,dataMapper,&QDataWidgetMapper::revert);
    connect(cbHomeCLI,&QCheckBox::stateChanged,this,&EditDialog::changeProperty);
    connect(dataMapper,&QDataWidgetMapper::currentIndexChanged,this,&EditDialog::initState);

    QGridLayout *layout(new QGridLayout());
    layout->addWidget(cbHomeCLI,2,2);

    setLayout(layout);
    setWindowTitle("....");

    dataMapper->setCurrentModelIndex(current);
}
```

```
void EditDialog::initState(int row)
{
    QStandardItemModel *mdl = qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel *>(dataMapper->model());

    if (mdl->item(row,3)->text() == "*31#")
        cbHomeCLI->setChecked(true);
    else
        cbHomeCLI->setChecked(false);
}
```

```
void EditDialog::changeProperty(int state)
{
   QCheckBox *from = qobject_cast<QCheckBox *>(sender());

    if (state)
        from->setProperty("useCLI",QString("*31#"));
    else
        from->setProperty("useCLI",QString(""));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution. Set an eventFilter in the EditDialog constructor with

```
cbHomeCLI->installEventFilter(this);
```

And the eventFilter uses the propertyChanged event

```
bool EditDialog::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::DynamicPropertyChange)
    {
        QDynamicPropertyChangeEvent *propEvent = static_cast<QDynamicPropertyChangeEvent *>(event);
        if (propEvent->propertyName() == "useCLI")
        {
            QCheckBox *cb = qobject_cast<QCheckBox *>(obj);
            if (cb->property("useCLI") == "")
                cb->setChecked(false);
            else
                cb->setChecked(true);
            return true;
        }
    }
    // standard event processing
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```